# How do I re-broadcast AngularJS event to child scopes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

Inside of my AngularJS app I have two views `itemList` and `favorites`, with common HTML code separated into a custom directive `listView`.
In order to differentiate the views, I attach different controllers to the views:

```
// itemList.html, controlled by ListCtrl
<list-view ng-controller="ItemListCtrl"></list-view>
...
// favorites.html, controlled by FavoritesCtrl
<list-view ng-controller="FavoritesListCtrl"></list-view>
```

Now I want `FavoritesListCtrl` to modify its local `$scope` in case his parent (`FavoritesCtrl`) receives a particular view-change event (namely, `$ionicView.beforeEntered`).

As far as I understand, these view-change-related events are broadcasted downwards from `$rootScope`, but listening `$rootScope.$on(...)` does not make sense as the listener will be triggered on every view change.

Thus I am trying to propagate the event by listening `$on` it within `FavoritesCtrl` and `$broadcast`-ing it to its child-scopes. This solution works if I broadcast custom event. But how do I **re-broadcast the same event** that `FavoritesCtrl` receives?

A little bit of context: I am developing a PhoneGap/Cordova app with Ionic framework, relying heavily on AngularJS features. Any ideas, suggestions, tips and feedback is greatly appreciated.

---

**Update:**
Here's a code inside of my `FavoritesListCtrl` which fails to catch the parent's event:

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    console.log('Inside FavoritesListCtrl: $ionicView.beforeEnter');
    ...
});
```

---

**This leads to infinite events:**

```
// FavoritesCtrl
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('$ionicView.beforeEnter');
)};

// FavoritesListCtrl
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    console.log('Inside ListCtrl: $ionicView.beforeEnter');
});
```

**This works:**

```
// FavoritesCtrl
$scope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent');

// FavoritesListCtrl
$scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function () {
    console.log('Inside ListCtrl: $ionicView.beforeEnter');
});
```

The problem is, it does not make much sense to define custom events for every parent event. Remember, I want `FavoritesListCtrl` to react on some of events received by its parent. I hope there is some way to propagate all parent's events to its children (without generating those events infinitely like in the case above).

Comment: does first time $broadcast works ? do you want $broadcast multiple times ?

Comment: `$broadcast` works infinitely-many times if triggered with the same event, but I want it to only pass the event once per parent event

Comment: still not clear ! `only pass the event once per parent event` what it means ?

Comment: Ok, I'll update my question with code examples :)

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, here's a way to do it.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, args) {
    if (!args.rebroadcasted) {
        console.log('Re-broadcasting!');

        $scope.$broadcast(event.name, {
            rebroadcasted: true
        });
    }
});
```

This code propagates particular event to the immediate children (child scopes), but it is impractical in case of deeper scope nesting (you can make sure the event reaches your target scope, but you'll have to update all the scopes in the chain to retransmit the same event).

Unfortunately, Angular seems not to provide a convenient way to listen to all the events, thus I would not recommend this solution to anyone. And I am also going to think of other possibilities.

I would still greatly appreciate opinions from experienced Angular developers about where to look for a better solution.

Comment: what is the difference between `$scope.$broadcast(event.name)` and $scope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent') ?

Comment: It's just a coding style preference. I find the former one to be better, as you only need to modify the event name in one place. In the latter case you'll just have to do that twice. The code would also work if you replace `event.name` with the name of the event. :)

Comment: I am using the same thing ... it's a bit surprising that $scope.$broadcast would also send event to the current scope ... a bit anti pattern I think ( well for my use )

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** re-broadcast the same event. You don't have control over `'$ionicView.beforeEnter'`. According to [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

> $ionicView.beforeEnter -  The view is about to enter and become the active view.

That means this event broadcast whenever any view has changed.

So you can broadcast your custom event that you tried or introduce a service that can communicate between controllers.

Comment: Thank you @Reza, for your answer. Unfortunately, the answer is not accurate. Moreover, I've figured out the code that answers my question.